# RabbitMQ Listen messages from queue from multiple servers

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-amqp

We are listening rabbimq messages from a clustered environment where we have multiple nodes. We want to make one node as a primary node that always listens to messages and by any chance, if that node becomes down, then we want to configure a secondary node which will listen to messages and serves as a backup in case a primary node goes down.

How does this configuration can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about one of the high-availability configurations (e.g. [mirrored queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html))?

Comment: I'm just a little confused on your use case and requirements.

Comment: @theMayer -  use Case : We have multiple nodes like backend , frontend , worker nodes for different purposes and I want that only 2 nodes , one primary and one secondary be configured which listens to rabbitmq queue . In case primary node fails , secondary node should serve the purpose

Comment: Just so we are clear though, you’re referring to failover of a singular consumer, and not the broker itself?

Comment: Yes , the consumer

Answer (score 0):

See [Exclusive Consumers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#exclusive-consumer).

The second (backup) consumer won't be able to consume until the first one dies.

Comment: Hello Gary - Thanks for the answer, but our multiple nodes connect to RabbitMQ via HAProxy so ideally for RabbitMQ it is only via one IP (of HAProxy) . Basically HAProxy then redirects to  nodes . How this configuration can be done so that one node is primary and other node is secondary consumer .